# How to cd and run npm in an nfs local xampp mounted server for mac

Tags: macos, npm, xampp, cd

`nfs://192.168.64.2/opt/lampp/htdocs` This is the directory where I want to `cd` using terminal yet I cant find it thanks for the help.